# Understanding wordpress the_content

Tags: mysql, wordpress, html

I have been asked to tweak a friend's website. The website was built for them using Wordpress by an agency they no longer work with. Problem is, I don't know very much about Wordpress, so I have some basic questions…

I can see (by comparing the source as viewed in my browser to the php templates that I can edit through the Wordpress interface) that the elements I need to modify are generated by the page's call to "the_content()". I don't really understand what this function does, but I think it pulls content for a given page from the MySQL database. Is that right?

I suspect that the Wordpress interface alone won't be enough to let me modify elements that come out of that database. Is that correct? How does anyone change, for example, the specific arrangement of text and images on a page if the relevant markup is fetched by "get_content()"?

Comment: google `wordpress the_content` will quickly find the docs that give you full explanation

Comment: Thank you charlietfl; I have looked at that documentation but although it explains how to use "the_content" in your wordpress page, it doesn't explain how it works, where the content it is fetching is stored (is it in the MySQL DB somewhere?), or whether there is a recommended way to change that content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing for WordPress or even just tweaking, it's really important to get at least a general understanding of the "loop" and how we use it for output. In order to output the content you need to call the method within the loop. If it's not within the loop it won't get inserted into your page.

(It works this way with all of your pages... index.php, page.php, single.php, post.php, etc... Your methods need to be placed within the loop in order for them to display within that page.)

Here's a simple example of the way the loop is used to output the title and content of posts:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> // loop start

    <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?> // loop end

    <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If you take a look at any standard WordPress theme (take Twenty Fourteen, for example), you'll find that `the_content()` is output together with calls to other elements (in this case - `the_title()`). If you want to want to change the arrangement of the specific elements within your page, just modify the order as they are within your loop, or check the WordPress Codex for additional options/methods.

Here's a short list of some other things you can display:

- `next_post_link` – Displays a link to the post published chronologically after the current post.
- `previous_post_link` – Displays a link to the post published chronologically before the
  current post.
- `the_category` – Displays the category or categories associated to the post or page being viewed.
- `the_author` – Displays the author of the post or page.
- `the_content` – Displays the main content for a post or page.
- `the_excerpt` – Displays the first 55 words of a post’s main content then with a [...] or read more link that goes to the full post. The length of excerpts can be controlled by using this slightly advanced method or by using the Excerpt field on the post edit page.
- `the_ID` – Displays the ID for the post or page.
- `the_meta` – Used to display custom fields.
- `the_shortlink` – Displays a link to the page or post using the url of the site using
  the ID of the post or page.
- `the_tags` – Displays the tag or tags associated with the post.
- `the_title` – Displays the title of the post or page.
- `the_time` – Displays the time or date for the post or page. This can be customized using the standard php date function formatting.

If you want to further customize some of these methods, you can do that within `functions.php`. Otherwise, all styling is done within your `styles.css`.

Comment: Thank you shmuli, but the things I need to change are all coming out of that call to "the_content". The source code for the page in question contains:
    <div id="mainfull" class="post">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <div id="homeForm">
When I look at the rendered page source in a browser, I can see the divs named "mainfull" and "homeForm"; and in between there's lots of other stuff that must get put there by the call to "the_content". So what is going on there? Where is that material coming from and how do I change it?

Comment: In between the "mainfull" and "homeForm" divs is the syntax of the WordPress loop. The basic idea of the loop is that it reads, "if there are any posts, do the following for each of the posts". It then checks what methods are contained within that loop, and for each of the posts, it generates that content from the database.

Comment: Take this example: `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1><?php endwhile; else: ?>`. If you did this, it would list out all of your post titles in h1, without any of the actual content. The general concept is that whatever you want to output, needs to be placed inside that loop (the source code that you're asking about).

Comment: Right, thank you. Now I'm sorry for being thick, but if we assume the content (the stuff fetched by the "the_content()" call) is in the database, what is the typical method that people use for modifying that content? I mean, you can't do it through the Wordpress UI can you? Or can you? I would need to modify… something… in a text editor and then upload it with an FTP client, right?

Comment: Maybe this will make it clearer what I'm asking: Apparently if you are using Wordpress to make web pages from scratch and you put a standard "loop" into your php, the page that comes out will have some standard placeholder text in it that goes like "This is an example page. It's different from a blog post because it will stay in one place"  Then farther down it will have some more prepackaged placeholder text that goes like "Hi there! I'm a bike messenger by day, aspiring actor by night, and this is my blog"
Where is this text coming from and how do you change it?

Comment: WordPress is a content management system, so there's no need to create pages in a text editor and upload it with an FTP client. You can create/modify content in the admin panel, and it then gets stored in the database. The code that you are addressing here, retrieves that content from the database and displays it on the face of the website. That's at the guts of any theme. On that note, once you have the basic skeleton of a theme (1. a css file with the appropriate header & 2. an index.php) you can even modify your code/theme within the WordPress backend, in the code editor.

Comment: Standard placeholder text (and I assume you mean actual content) can be removed/modified from the admin planel (www.example.com/wp-admin) or from the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61086/discussion-between-nttaylor-and-shmuli).

Answer (score 1):

Probably your content is being generated by a shortcode.

You can modify the content that wordpress fetches from the database with `the_content` filter:

```
// returns the content of $GLOBALS['post']
// if the page is called 'debug'
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
  // assuming you have created a page/post entitled 'debug'
  if ($GLOBALS['post']->post_name == 'debug') {
    return var_export($GLOBALS['post'], TRUE );
  }
  // otherwise returns the database content
  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

maybe its not the best solution but you can modify the content before it gets output.

[source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)